# Image from gallery is not pasted into ImageView in Fragment

Tags: android, imageview, gallery

I'm aware that there are a lot of similar questions here, but my case is quite stupid. Or I am.

So, I've got following simple layout:

[image: Layout mockup]

XML structure:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:contentDescription="Description" />

    <TextView/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager />

    <Button />

</RelativeLayout>
```

On Button click gallery is opened, user picks some image and it is placed into ImageView

I've created test activity with following code and it works perfect:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");

                startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(uri);
        }

    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:contentDescription="image" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pick Image"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the original project this code doesn't work. Gallery is called promptly, all methods are called as well, but image is simply not pasted into ImageView:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                chooserIntent.setType("image/*");

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });

}

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(uri);

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image is picked successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }   
}
```

I've tried to use following snippets so far with `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (just in case):

**Snippet 1**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
}
```

**Snippet 2**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
}
```

**Snippet 3**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
}
```

**Snippet 4**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }       
}
```

No results yet. I have no idea what may be a problem. I will be very grateful for any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And suddenly I managed to find an answer, after 30 minutes of question posting

As my ImageView is in fragment, it is being destroyed when gallery is launched and recreated right after image picking. During recreation ImageView is drawn with initial values and Uri of picked image is lost

The solution is to save Uri somewhere and apply it on fragment creation with conditional statement. Or prevent fragment recreation somehow

I hope it may be helpful for someone